# How to work with the data parameter of the success function of a post?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to make a `post` to a `Jelix` script :

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $("#btnCalculerNote").on("click",function(){
            iIdUser = $("#id_user").val () ;
            $.post(
                "{/literal}{jurl 'default:calculerNote', array()}{literal}",
                {"id_utilisateur": iIdUser},
                function(data)
                {
                    alert ("Calcul des notes terminé") ;
                    // here I want to get the returned url inside the data param
                }
            );

        });
    });
</script>
{/literal}
```

Inside the "default" controller :

```
function calculerNote ()
{
    $rep = $this->getResponse ("redirect");
    ...
    $rep->action = "default:index"; // default is name of the controller , index is the name of the action inside the default controller
    return $rep ;
 }
```

As you can see I want to redirect the page to the "default:index" url. So how to get it inside the function of the `$.post` ?

Comment: Instead of redirecting from controller post method..just send back some json token value back to ajax call and then use `location.href = ...` inside ajax callback to redirect.

Comment: so what should be the value returned by the json ?

Comment: Though I am not familiar with php but may be you can return the url where you want to redirect as json object and then use it inside ajax success callback to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your conditions

Why don't your try like this

```
function calculerNote ()
{
    $rep = $this->getResponse ("redirect"); 
    ...
    return json_encode(['action' => 'default:index'] ;
 }
```

And in js success function you can use like this

```
window.location.herf = data.action;
```